# Radiobuttons not showing up

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

I use the below code to have a quick and easy way to get user input, in this case choosing an option from a group of radiobuttons.

```
internal static int multipleChoice(IEnumerable<string> options, int indexOfDefault, string header)
{
    string[] input = options.ToArray();
    int result = indexOfDefault;
    Form promt = new Form();
    promt.Text = header;
    promt.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
    List<RadioButton> buttonsInForm = new List<RadioButton>();

    int maxPerColumn = 6;
    int column = 0;
    int line = 0;

    int hSpace = 25;
    int vSpace = 180;

    for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        RadioButton btn = new RadioButton();
        if(i == indexOfDefault)
            btn.Checked = true;

        btn.Text = input[i];
        btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point((column + 1) * vSpace, (line + 1) * hSpace);
        line++;
        if(line > maxPerColumn)
        {
            line = 0;
            column++;
        }

        btn.CheckedChanged += 
            (sender, e) => 
        {
            RadioButton caller = (RadioButton)sender;
            if(!caller.Checked)
                return;

            result = buttonsInForm.IndexOf(caller);
        };

        buttonsInForm.Add(btn);
    }

    promt.Width = column * vSpace + 150;

    if(buttonsInForm.Count < maxPerColumn)
        promt.Height = (buttonsInForm.Count + 2) * vSpace;
    else
        promt.Height = (maxPerColumn + 2) * vSpace;

    promt.Controls.AddRange(buttonsInForm.ToArray());
    promt.ShowDialog();

    return result;
}
```

Example call

```
List<string> whatEv = new List<string>();
whatEv.Add("one");
whatEv.Add("two");
whatEv.Add("three");
string foo  = promts.multipleChoice(whatEv, 1, "form title");
```

The issue is:
When used, it does show a form, but no Radiobuttons.(also the sizing of the form doesn't work as intended, but that is for me for later)
I already stepped through the loop with the debugger and all buttons looked fine.
Also I am not getting any exceptions or compiler warnings.
My *assumption* is that I am forgetting something to set something inside the for-loop, but what?

Comment: `vspace` calculations seems not right. Just for test purpose change `int vspace = 50`.

Comment: @HassanNisar yep, that was the issue, Grant posten an answer about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your code to test it. The radio buttons are on your `Form`. They're just pushed off the right side.

Place a breakpoint on the following line:

```
btn.Location =
    new System.Drawing.Point((column + 1) * vSpace, (line + 1) * hSpace);
```

And inspect the value of `(column + 1) * vSpace`. You'll have to correct the calculation it's doing, or make the `Form` wider.

Comment: as simple as that. I thought, my form was wide enough. Also I keep forgetting that winfroms just doesn't care or tell you if you place stuff out of reach and sight.